# setup ipv6 route so that it does not override v4 for all host's traffic

Tags: networking, router, vpn, routing, ipv6

I connect to an enterprise network via a virtual private network in bridge mode that assigns a /64 public IPv6 subnet.

The problem is, when connected, the IPv6 route is set to ::/0, this means that IPv6 is preferred for all the traffic on that host. If I try to visit google (or any other site that listens on both IPv6 and IPv4 [IPv6 has priority]) I connect to it using the virtual network IPv6 address, and not my host's default address.

I would like to use my host's default IPv4 address for all traffic generated on that host, and just have one IPv6 address from the remote side lifted on my machine, so that I can bind a service that listens on it, but it is not used by default by all my applications.

I would also like to know if it's possible to connect two instances of this network so that i get two /64 IPv6 subnets on the same host. Which IPv6 gateway should I use for each one for my use case?

Comment: It's fairly common for enterprise VPNs to route _all_ traffic to the corporate network, but it does happen. Are you saying this is happening for IPv6 but _not_ for IPv4?

Answer (score 2):

IPv4 and IPv6 routing are entirely separate.

When connecting to a host by name, *the application chooses* whether to use the v4 or the v6 IP address. The routing tables have no say in this.

::/0 is the default route for IPv6, just as 0.0.0.0/0 is for IPv4. If you don't want it to point into the tunnel just re-set it to your normal gateway.

Normally, the VPN software sets an *additional* default route *with a low metric* - just make sure your local default route has a *lower* metric, so it is preferred.

Depending on the VPN gateway and client, connecting multiple instances might not be possible. Otherwise, you'll have to check with the administrator.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. My host does not have a default ipv6 route. I do not have IPv6 connectivity unless I connect to that tunnel. I connect to that tunnel via IPv4, and I also get IPv6 on the virtual device created by that tunnel. So, I am not sure with what to replace the default IPv6 gateway ::/0 added by the tunnel in order to just be reachable on IPv6 but do not forward all my traffic by default.

Comment: It would be smart to include necessary details in your answer. With only IPv4 locally, just deactivate v6 in your browser/application. Or, with a specific route for VPN access, delete the ::/0 route.

Comment: I have tried to delete the ::/0 route but if I do this the Ipv6 address is not reachable from the internet any more, it cannot receive even ping.

Comment: I give up. If you don't us the important details we can't help you. Now you need to be connected to from the Internet?

Comment: I am sorry. I don't know what more detail you need. I have a VPN that gives me a /64 IPv6. I want to use it, but not forward all my traffic. Just listen on my web server on IPv6 and have an AAAA record.